# How to increment the filename if file already exists

Tags: .net, vb.net

In my vb.net winform application, I am moving the file (ex: sample.xls from one folder to another. If file already exists with the same name, the new file name should be incremented (ex:sample(1).xls). How can i acheive this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078003/c-how-would-you-make-a-unique-filename-by-adding-a-number for a C# version of this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi here's a pretty "procedural" answer:

```
Dim counter As Integer = 0

Dim newFileName As String = orginialFileName

While File.Exists(newFileName)
    counter = counter + 1
    newFileName = String.Format("{0}({1}", orginialFileName, counter.ToString())
End While
```

you will need an imports statement for System.IO

Comment: Not a good solution if there are millions of files with the same name, for instance an image sequence.

Answer (score 6):

The above procedure add the counter at the end, but i my case a want to keep the extention of the file, so i have expanded the function to this:

```
Public Shared Function FileExistIncrementer(ByVal OrginialFileName As String) As String
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim NewFileName As String = OrginialFileName
    While File.Exists(NewFileName)
        counter = counter + 1
        NewFileName = String.Format("{0}\{1}-{2}{3}", Path.GetDirectoryName(OrginialFileName), Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(OrginialFileName), counter.ToString(), Path.GetExtension(OrginialFileName))
    End While
    Return NewFileName
End Function
```