# How do I not overwrite files when making them?

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I create two files with the same name, it overwrites it. I want the second file to be [Name] (#)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to increment the filename if file already exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264098/how-to-increment-the-filename-if-file-already-exists)

Answer (score 2):

This code creates the next file in the range of files named

> MyFile.txt
>   MyFile1.txt
>   MyFile2.txt
>   MyFile3.txt
>   ...

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim fn = "C:\Data\MyFile"
Dim ext = ".txt"

If File.Exists(fn + ext) Then
    Do
        i = i + 1
    Loop While File.Exists(fn + i.ToString() + ext)
    fn = fn + i.ToString()
End If
WriteFile(fn + ext)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
File.Exists(curFile)
```

Check if the name already exist and then rename the new one in your code
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx