# PHP Rename File name if Exists Append Number to End

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, rename, file-exists

I'm trying to rename the file name of an image when it's uploaded if it exists, say if my file name is `test.jpg` and it already exists I want to rename it as `test1.jpg` and then `test2.jpg` and so on. With the code I've written its changing my file name like so `test1.jpg` and then `test12.jpg` any advice on fixing this would be great thank!

**PHP**

```
$name = $_FILES['picture']['name'];
$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$i = 1;
while(file_exists('tmp/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$actual_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: clear the variable $actual_name once used because its a loop by doing some what like this , $acutal_name = ''

Comment: You could test the name with `$i` in the `while` loop .. as in `"tmp/".$actual_name.$i.".".$extension` and create the value `$name` after the while loop `$name = "tmp/".$actual_name.$i.".".$extension`

Comment: i am usually not that guy, but you should really think about trying out my answer and making it the accecpted one. have a nice day :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here's a minor modification that I think should do what you want:

```
$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$i = 1;
while(file_exists('tmp/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. You are my hero

Comment: It looks like this answer just appends always by 1, so: foo.bar -> foo1.bar -> foo11.bar etc. It technically works, but anyone who worked with files before would expect, that the number increases (foo2.bar) and not just appends.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired from @Jason answer, i created a function which i deemed shorter and more readable filename format.

```
function newName($path, $filename) {
    $res = "$path/$filename";
    if (!file_exists($res)) return $res;
    $fnameNoExt = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $i = 1;
    while(file_exists("$path/$fnameNoExt ($i).$ext")) $i++;
    return "$path/$fnameNoExt ($i).$ext";
}
```

#### Example:

```
$name = "foo.bar";
$path = 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/ikreports';
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
  $newName = newName($path, $name);
  file_put_contents($newName, 'asdf');
}
```

---

## New version (2022):

```
function newName2($fullpath) {
  $path = dirname($fullpath);
  if (!file_exists($fullpath)) return $fullpath;
  $fnameNoExt = pathinfo($fullpath,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $ext = pathinfo($fullpath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

  $i = 1;
  while(file_exists("$path/$fnameNoExt ($i).$ext")) $i++;
  return "$path/$fnameNoExt ($i).$ext";
}
```

#### Usage:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++) {
  $newName = newName2($fullpath);
  file_put_contents($newName, 'asdf');
}
```

Comment: It looks like this answer just appends always by ' (1)', so: foo.bar -> foo (1).bar -> foo (1) (1).bar etc. It technically works, but anyone who worked with files before would expect, that the number increases (foo (2).bar) and not just appends.

Comment: "it looks like"? Have you tried? Perhaps u used it wrong.

Comment: I provided an answer myself, there you should be able to see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

I checked SO and found a nice C# answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078003/c-how-would-you-make-a-unique-filename-by-adding-a-number/24563008#24563008), so I ported it for PHP:

```
['extension' => $extension] = pathinfo($filePath);
$count = 0;
while (file_exists($filePath) === true) {
    if ($count === 0) {
        $filePath = str_replace($extension, '[' . ++$count . ']' . ".$extension", $filePath);
    } else {
        $filePath = str_replace("[$count].$extension", '[' . ++$count . ']' . ".$extension", $filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: $extension variable not declared.