# Check if file_exists, then add a 1 to the end if it does

Tags: php

I have this code I've written (upload.php), however, when it uploads, I cant seem to be able to save a new file with a one - I have also tried to find a way to do this, however can't seem to be able to get it to work.

[upload.php]

```php
<?php

/* Get the name of the uploaded file */
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

/* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
$location = "upload/".$filename;

/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { 
  echo 'Success'; 
} else { 
  echo 'Failure'; 
}

?>
```

Heres part of [index.php]:

```html
<div class="chat-message" id="chat-area">
    
    <div class="message-content-grid">
        <div class="add-file">
            <label for="fileupload">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>
            </label>

            <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" onchange="uploadFile()"/>
        </div>

        <div class="message-area">
            <form id="send-message-area">
                <textarea id="sendie" maxlength ="300" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </form>
        </div>
    <div>

    
</div>

<script>document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollTop = document.getElementById('chat-area').scrollHeight;</script>

<script>
    async function uploadFile() {
        let formData = new FormData(); 
        formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);
        await fetch('upload.php', {
            method: "POST", 
            body: formData
        }); 
        alert('The file has been uploaded successfully.');
    }
</script>
```

So when you click the upload icon:

```html
<label for="fileupload">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-plus"></i>
</label>

<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" onchange="uploadFile()"/>
```

It will run the javascript:

```html
<script>
async function uploadFile() {
    let formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append("file", fileupload.files[0]);
    await fetch('upload.php', {
        method: "POST", 
        body: formData
    }); 
    alert('The file has been uploaded successfully.');
}
</script>
```

Which will intern, run the php script in [upload.php].

```php
<?php

/* Get the name of the uploaded file */
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];

/* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
$location = "upload/".$filename;

/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { 
  echo 'Success'; 
} else { 
  echo 'Failure'; 
}

?>
```

What I want is to check if there is a file with the same name and if so, add a 1 or 2 or 3 depending on if that file also exists (file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt ...) Anyone have any ideas? Thx

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136562/231316

Comment: Thanks so much, I tried this last night and couldn't get it to work, but was just tired I think! It works now thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed:

```php
<?php

/* Get the name of the uploaded file */
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$actual_name = pathinfo($name,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$original_name = $actual_name;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$i = 1;
while(file_exists('upload/'.$actual_name.".".$extension))
{           
    $actual_name = (string)$original_name.$i;
    $name = $actual_name.".".$extension;
    $i++;
}

/* Choose where to save the uploaded file */
$location = "upload/". $name;


/* Save the uploaded file to the local filesystem */
if ( move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $location) ) { 
  echo 'Success'; 
} else { 
  echo 'Failure'; 
}

?>
```