# How to append key to an image's name asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, model-view-controller

Here is my code to append postfix to an image:

```
private void SaveUpload(SledBuck sledBuck )
{
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {                
        var postFix = "_" + sledBuck.Id;
        for (var index = 0; index < Request.Files.Count; index++)
        {
             if (Request.Files[index].ContentLength > 0)
             {                   
                 var hpf = Request.Files[index];
                 var postedFileName = string.Format("{0}-{1}", Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName), postFix);

                 string folderPath =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"];

                 var savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folderPath), postedFileName);
                        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName); // Save the file

              }
         }
     }
}
```

Let's say the image's name is image.jpg. I want to append primary key to it's name before updating it like image_1.jpg. For the code above the postedFileName = image.jpg_1 which is not what I want. How can I append the Id properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How would you make a unique filename by adding a number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078003/c-how-would-you-make-a-unique-filename-by-adding-a-number)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so basically what you get as `hpf.FileName` is FileName  + Extension. You need to get the extension and work accordingly,

so proceed like this :

```
var hpf = Request.Files[index];

var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(hpf.FileName);
var FileNameWithoutExtension = hpf.FileName.Replace(FileExtension, "");
var FileUniqueName = String.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", FileNameWithoutExtension, GenerateDateTimeStamp(), FileExtension);

string folderPath =  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"];

var savedFileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(folderPath), FileUniqueName);
hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName); // Save the file
```

where `GenerateDateTimeStamp()` is

```
public string GenerateDateTimeStamp()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("ddmmyyyyMMhhssttt");
}
```

in here you can have your primary keys aswell.

this should give you some idea