# code to handle the case when the uploaded file has the same name as the file already existing in the uploads folder

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need the codes to handle the case when the uploaded file 
                has the same name as the file already existing in the uploads folder.
                For example if in the folder uploads there is already a file named "myfile.pdf"
                and you want to upload another file called "myfile.pdf" the new file should be automatically 
                renamed "myfile(new).pdf".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: How would you make a unique filename by adding a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078003/c-how-would-you-make-a-unique-filename-by-adding-a-number)

Comment: @CodeCaster please make me correct if i am wrong because as per my understanding he asked how to stop images uploading without changing their names not like you recommend above article.

Comment: @Munawar last sentence reads _"the new file should be automatically renamed "myfile(new).pdf""_, this does not indicate that such a thing should be blocked.