# Nice way to do recursion with ES6 promises?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Here's what I've got:

```
function nextAvailableFilename(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        FileSystem.exists(path, function (exists) {
            if (!exists) return resolve(path);

            var ext = Path.extname(path);
            var pathWithoutExt = path.slice(0, -ext.length);

            var match = /\d+$/.exec(pathWithoutExt);
            var number = 1;

            if (match) {
                number = parseInt(match[0]);
                pathWithoutExt = pathWithoutExt.slice(0, -match[0].length);
            }

            ++number;

            nextAvailableFilename(pathWithoutExt + number + ext).then(function () {
                return resolve.apply(undefined, arguments);
            }, function () {
                return reject.apply(undefined, arguments);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

But I don't like that block at the end -- isn't there a way to 'replace' the current promise with the next one in the stack rather than having one promise resolve the next like I've done here?

Comment: You can create a wrapper object which just has a stack of promises, handles the actual resolve/reject and just move on to the next promise

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say. I should create a separate object that maintains a stack, and resolve/reject them more or less how I've done now? What benefit would that provide?

Comment: It would essentially be aesthetic, but you do have the benefit of cleaner code so it should be easy to follow and if you use prototypes lighter on memory use

Comment: Why aren't you just chaining promises?

Comment: @jfriend00 Wutchya mean? How do I "chain" them?

Comment: In thinking about a better way to do this, I'm trying to understand what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you just trying to find the next numeric ending file of a given filename that doesn't already exist?  If so, this general technique has race conditions unless you actually create the file.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want a unique filename, but I want to be as similar to the original as possible.

Comment: Do you understand that this general technique (returning a filename that is not yet created) has a race condition?  If anyone else is also doing this, then you both may think you have the next unused filename and both end up trying to use the same filename.  This would show up immediately if you used clustering to add scale.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes, I understand that. I'm replacing it with a file create now; thanks for pointing that out. But the original problem still stands, I will just be replacing `exists` with 'create'

Comment: @Mark Very simple answer to the chaining question: When you write a `.then(fn...... ,` function, that can return a value. If it does, then `.then()` returns that value (in a new promise object). Or, if said value is a promise, it returns the result of that promise, etc. I find it to be a handy way of "converting" a promise into a more specific format that the caller will need; or, making a second necessary asynchronous request.

Comment: FYI, if you generated a lot of these files in the same directory and you always started with a low numbered filename as the argument to your function, this scheme is pretty inefficient because it has to iterate through all the files that already exist with separate file calls for each.  If you're always passing the most recently used filename into the function, then it would not be as inefficient.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm not expecting a lot of duplicate filenames. Each client gets their own directory, but if they wanted to name every file the same I suppose they could. I might tackle that problem later :-) There's a [good solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909521/how-to-store-values-persistenly-of-files-in-a-directory/909545#909545) but it's a bit trickier to write in async I think.

Comment: No problem, just mentioning it in case efficiency was important.  If there are lots of conflicting files, it might be more efficient to find the next guess by doing a `fs.readdir()` and looking through that array for the best filename to try next since you can skip over all existing names with that one file call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that uses promise chaining and file create to avoid the race condition.  I used the bluebird promise library so I can use promises with the `fs` library just to simplify the code and error handling:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
var path = require('path');

// Creates next available xxx/yyy/foo4.txt numeric sequenced file that does
// not yet exist.  Returns the new filename in the promise
// Calling this function will create a new empty file.
function nextAvailableFilename(filename) {
    return fs.openAsync(filename, "wx+").then(function(fd) {
        return fs.closeAsync(fd).then(function() {
            return filename;
        });
    }, function(err) {
        if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') {
            // unexpected file system error
            // to avoid possible looping forever, we must bail 
            // and cause rejected promise to be returned
            throw err;
        }
        // Previous file exists so reate a new filename
        // xxx/yyy/foo4.txt becomes xxx/yyy/foo5.txt
        var ext = path.extname(filename);
        var filenameWithoutExt = filename.slice(0, -ext.length);
        var number = 0;
        var match = filenameWithoutExt.match(/\d+$/);
        if (match) {
            number = parseInt(match[0], 10);
            filenameWithoutExt = filenameWithoutExt.slice(0, -match[0].length);
        }
        ++number;
        // call this function again, returning the promise 
        // which will cause it to chain onto previous promise
        return nextAvailableFilename(filenameWithoutExt + number + ext);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between `wx` and `wx+`? Also, `fs.close` is async -- we should probably wait until the file is fully closed before returning.

Comment: wx+ just opens for reading and writing.  Probably works the same in this context as wx.  Yes, it should wait until `fs.close()` is done since the caller will want to use the file.  I've edited to do that.  I also fixed a type to use the promisified versions of the functions.

Comment: Cool. I see what you mean by "chaining" now. I read about that before, but I've never used that feature before. Pretty handy. This is definitely nicer with the promisified versions of fs.open/close.

Comment: @Mark - see my note at the end about infinite looping.  When the `fs.openAsync()` fails, it needs to proceed to try another name ONLY in certain error conditions.  For example, if a bogus path was passed in front of the filename (a path that doesn't exist) or a path where you don't have create privileges, this will loop forever.  So, basically, it needs to check `err` to see if the error is that the file exists already.  Since node.js doc is horrible in this regard, a test file will have to examine error codes to see which one to look for.

Comment: @Mark, the code in the question is now tested and works.  I added the proper error code detection to avoid looping and fixed several typos.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution too that doesn't depend on bluebird.promisify. It *should* handle the case where file creation fails for a reason other than it already exists.

```
function createFile(path) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        FileSystem.open(path, 'wx', function (err, fd) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            FileSystem.close(fd, function (err) {
                if (err) return reject(err);
                return resolve();
            });
        });
    });
}

// todo: make more efficient by multiplying numbers by 2 or something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1078898/65387

function nextFile(path) {
    return createFile(path).then(function () {
        return path;
    }, function (err) {
        if (err.code !== 'EEXIST') throw err; // error other than "file exists"

        var ext = Path.extname(path);
        var pathWithoutExt = path.slice(0, -ext.length);

        var match = /\d+$/.exec(pathWithoutExt);
        var number = 2;

        if (match) {
            number = parseInt(match[0]) + 1;
            pathWithoutExt = pathWithoutExt.slice(0, -match[0].length);
        }

        return nextFile(pathWithoutExt + number + ext);
    });
}
```

Comment: FYI, once you start manually promisifying some `fs` calls and really learning how to use promises, you will quickly find that you simply want the whole `fs` api to be promisified.  Further once you get into promises, yuo will quickly find that the extra features that Bluebird (or other promise libraries) offers are really, really useful.  I could understand avoiding a third party if you were trying to make something small and light for redistribution, but for you own project a promisified `fs` module is gold.

Comment: Your error handling does not work properly. You need to `throw err`, not `return err` when checking the `err.errno` . `return err` will cause the promise to be resolved with `err` as the returned value, not rejected. If you throw inside of a `.then()` handler, then it will cause the promise to be rejected. If you return anything other than a promise, that will be come the resolved value.

Comment: FYI, when I run this code on Windows, I'm seeing `err.errno === -4075` when the file already exists.  Perhaps `err.code` is more cross platform?

Comment: Good points. Thank you for your help. I wasn't quite sure if I needed to throw or return; I thought returning would maintain the present resolve/reject state. I switched `err.errno` for `err.code`.

Comment: Yeah, a good thing to learn with promises.  If you have a `.then()` error handling function, then that promise assumes you have "handled" the error so if you just return from that handler, then the resulting promise is resolved, not rejected.  To have a handler and make the resulting promise be rejected, you can either return a rejected promise or throw an error (which it will catch and turn into a rejected promise).